# Open mobile share sheet using flutter web in mobile browser

Tags: flutter, dart, share-plus

I want to share content on social sites using mobile browser in my flutter web site
i used [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) but it is not opening the share sheet just opening the email if i provide subject in it.

```
 Share.share("This is a text message", subject: "");
```

Comment: I have same problem, In web it only open mail applicaion, not any other messenger .Dose any one solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since not all browsers are supported, we can check the [availability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#browser_compatibility) of the API before attempting to call it from Flutter Web.

On Safari(Mac OS/iOS) and Chrome(Windows/Chrome OS) this works just fine:

[image]

I have the following working:

```dart
Widget buildShareButton(BuildContext context, Event event) {
  final bool result = _canUseWebShare();

  if (result) {
    logger.i('Using newer share button.');
    return _buildSharePlusButton(context, event);
  } else {
    logger.i('Using fallback share button.');
    return _buildFallbackShareButton(context, event);
  }
}

bool _canUseWebShare() {
  try {
    final js.JsObject navigator = js.context['navigator'] as js.JsObject;
    return navigator.hasProperty('canShare');
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

Widget _buildSharePlusButton(BuildContext context, Event event) {
  return IconButton(
    tooltip: 'Share too...',
    icon: Icon(Icons.adaptive.share_outlined),
    onPressed: () async {
      // Using Share Plus
      Share.share(
        '${event.url}\n\n${event.description}',
        subject: event.name,
      );
    },
  );
}

Widget _buildFallbackShareButton(BuildContext context, Event event) {
  return IconButton(
    tooltip: 'Share too...',
    icon: Icon(Icons.adaptive.share_outlined),
    onPressed: () async {
      // older implementation
    },
  );
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/share_plus/share_plus/lib/src/share_plus_web.dart
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Share_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/canShare